# choice parameter and extended choice parameters not working in Blue Oean interface in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

choice parameter and extended choice parameters not working in Blue Ocean interface in Jenkins.

I have a huge list in the drop down menu. I wanted to have a drop down with filterable option or make it as a extended choice for the users to select the option easily in the Jenkins. I have tried to use Choice and extended choice parameter in the input. choice parameter and extended choice parameters are not supported in Blue Ocean interface in Jenkins.

Please let me know how to proceed?

Comment: Just use Jenkins Classic (the regular UI) for building the parametrized build,
 it supports all parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

BlueOcean only supports these types:

```java
export const supportedInputTypesMapping = {
    BooleanParameterDefinition: Boolean,
    ChoiceParameterDefinition: Choice,
    TextParameterDefinition: Text,
    StringParameterDefinition: String,
    PasswordParameterDefinition: Password,
};
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/master/blueocean-core-js/src/js/parameter/index.js#L20

So either raise a Jenkins ticket or use Classic view or translate your job to use those types only.